# How to center a div on outlook mail?

Tags: html, outlook

As we already know word engine is not the best engine out there but many companies use outlook so it must be supported at the time we send emails, recently i am facing the problem of keeping a div centered using tables and as it works on other mail clients like thunderbird, mail, gmail, etc.. it just doesn't work on outlook so the padding that is visible at the sides disappears and the header becomes full width. so how do i center the div?

```
<!-- Code updated with fix -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Newsletter</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <!-- Left Padding -->
        <td></td>
        <!-- Centered Content -->
        <td width="600">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0">
                <!-- Body start -->
                <tr>
                    <td width="600">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="100%">
                                    <div width="100%" style="height:60px; background-color: #777777;">
                                        ...
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Body end -->
            </table>
        </td>
        <!-- Right Padding -->
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you try this code with the first parent table? `<table width="600px" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0 auto;">`

Comment: @GibinEalias It stills do the same.

Comment: Hmm! In that case, try adding `<td width="200px"></td>` as the left and right padding on you actual code and see whether it works. If it does, change the pixel value with percentage and try again.

Comment: I say don't stick to 90s code and use tables within tables within tables within more tables - email clients are getting better at handling html but still way behind

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs The problem is that word engine doesn't have good support for positioning or even simple stuff like margin or padding so it must be done the old way.

Comment: @DJava exactly my point :) it hardly supports any HTML elements haha just use <td width="spacer-length" as your padding and margins :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs yeah thank you a lot, it worked!

Comment: @DJava huzzah! :) glad to help!